# Moving a DriveItem from folder to the root of the drive in SharePoint Graph API

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph, azure-ad-graph-api

I have managed to move a DriveItem between folders without problems using this method:

```
public DriveItem MoveDriveItem(string siteId, string sourceItemId, string destinationItemId)
{
    var driveItem = new DriveItem
    {
        ParentReference = new ItemReference
        {
            Id = destinationItemId,
        }
    };
    return graphClient.Sites[siteId].Drive.Items[sourceItemId]
                   .Request()
                   .UpdateAsync(driveItem).Result;
}
```

Now I have an edge case where I need to move a folder/document to the root of the SharePoint site. The problem is that the root does not have an "itemid". How would I go about moving a folder/document to the root of the document library?

I have tried to use the id of the drive but that does not seem to work.

An example folder structure:

```
a ->
    b ->
        document.docx
```

How I would like it to be after the move:

```
a ->
b ->
    document.docx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using following code:

```
var driveItem = new DriveItem()
{
    ParentReference = new ItemReference()
    {
        Id = (await graphClient.Sites["site id"].Drives["drive id"].Root.Request().GetAsync()).Id
    }
};
var allItems = await graphClient.Drive.Items[documentId].Request().UpdateAsync(driveItem);
```

Basically you need to pass ID of root folder of the document library which you can access using **Drives["driveId"].Root**

It's working in my case

Comment: That is working beautifully! Thanks.